# Compiling and running Exploit-DB code

Tags: javascript, exploit

I found this exploit on exploit-db, and it matches my router version. I'm somewhat a n00b, and I wanted to know if anyone knew how to use this exploit to exploit a router. Or rather, how to compile and execute this exploit.

I've done an exhaustive search, and still couldn't find a way.

http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/35325/

Thanks.
P.S- This language, is I'm not wrong, is javascript right? So how do I compile and run this exploit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

These are just [HTTP GET methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods): The router seems to suffer from [remote directory traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) (you're not supposed to access parent directories from a URL, using `../`).

You can do that with anything that can do HTTP requests (browsers, tools, most programming languages, etc.). In the "exploit", Mozilla Firefox browser was used. Just go to this URL, it's simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

This exploit is 12 years old, and I would be suprised if it still wouldn't be fixed. Also **the list DOESN'T contain ANY javascript**, and doesn't tell you the exact way to exploit the weakness, however you can read description as it says:

> The router suffers from an authenticated file inclusion vulnerability
>   (LFI) when input passed thru the 'getpage' parameter to 'webproc'
>   script is not properly verified before being used to include files.
>   This can be exploited to include files from local resources with
>   directory traversal attacks.

Comment: Not exactly. The exploit was only written last month. You'll be surprised how many routers still use mini httpd 1.9 2003.

Comment: So any idea HOW i exploit it?

Comment: Ok. That comment was a bit arrogant. I'm sorry 'bout that. Still. HOW do i exploit my router?